# When using a string tokenizer , how do I check the next character after a token if it is a delimiter?

Tags: java, string, delimiter, stringtokenizer

Say for example I have a string which is the following "3*x+(b[3]+c)+x"

And my delimiters are " \t*+-/()[]"

When I use the string tokenizer to split the string and I get to token "b", how can I check to make sure that the next delimiter is "[".

I need to do this so that token "x" is different from token "b", as token x represents a simple variable and token b represents an array in the program I am trying to construct.

I am trying to write this code in Java.

Comment: You can't. If your character is meaningful you shouldn't use it as a delimiter to split.

Comment: What language is expression?

Comment: I am trying to write this code in java

Comment: why dont you use simple string processing? is it tokenzer or nothing?

Comment: @gpasch variable names can be really long thats why I want to use string tokenizer

Comment: None of these characters are delimiters in any programming language. They are all operators. You are using the wrong tool for the job,

Comment: @EJP I am defining my delimiters to be these characters. I want a way to separate all the variables from the operators using StringTokenizer. My program requires me to use StringTokenizer.

Comment: Your program doesn't require you.  Maybe you assignment requirements do .... but that is a different matter.  (Or to put it another way, if your program "requires" it, then change the program!)

Comment: I know what you're doing, and how you're doing it. I'm telling you it's wrong. This is not how programming languages are analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

> When using a string tokenizer , how do I check the next character after a token if it is a delimiter?

If you use the [3 argument constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-) for `StringTokenizer`, then 3rd argument says whether or not the delimiters are returned as tokens.

However<sup>1</sup>, this still leaves you with the awkward problem of dealing with whitespace.  For example "1+1" gives you 3 tokens, but "1 + 1" gives you 5 tokens.  You either need to:

- pick a better way<sup>2</sup> to tokenize the input,
- filter out any white-space "tokens" before you start analyzing them, or
- remove any whitespace from the input string before you tokenize it.

---

<sup>1 - I'm inclined to agree with @EJP that `StringTokenizer` is the wrong tool for this job.  You could make it work, but IMO you shouldn't.  (Unless you have been explicitly directed to do this.)</sup>

<sup>2 - Better ways might be `StreamTokenizer`, `String.split` (with a cunning regex involving lookaheads or lookbehinds), a tokenizer generated using ANTLR, javacc or some other parser generator, or ... a hand built tokenizer.</sup>